# How do I sum data over 3 month ranges?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a report where I need to add totals for a column and group them by company selected. I have to do this in T-SQL for 4 ranges:
0-3 Months, 3-6 months, 6-12 months, >12 months
I am confused about how this would be implemented in T-SQL.
There is a balance column on which I have to total.
The problem I am not able to understand is summary over those date ranges. How can this be done in T-SQL?

The user should input the company choice and a date and based on it, I have to generate summary of balance column within the ranges specified, which were
0-3 Months, 3-6 months, 6-12 months, >12 months

I am thinking of it this way: I am thinking of it this way:
Make ranges of date, so : suppose @date is user selected date
then:

```
DECLARE @daterange1start DATE = @date
DECLARE @daterange1end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,3,@daterange1start))
DECLARE @daterange2start DATE = @daterange1end
DECLARE @daterange2end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,3,@daterange2start))
DECLARE @daterange3start DATE = @daterange2end
DECLARE @daterange3end DATE = (SELECT DATEADD(m,6,@daterange3start)) '
```

And then using case

```
SUM (CASE WHEN  dueDate BETWEEN @daterange1start AND @daterange1end THEN    Balance ELSE 0 END) AS '0-3 Months', 
SUM (CASE WHEN dueDate BETWEEN @daterange2start AND @daterange2end THEN Balance ELSE 0 END) AS '3-6 Months',
SUM (CASE WHEN dueDate BETWEEN @daterange3start AND @daterange3end THEN Balance ELSE 0 END) AS '6-12 Months''
```

Am I thinking of it the right way in terms of a correct solution?

Thank you.

Comment: post input data and expected output OR create sqlfiddle

Comment: I'm not sure I understand those ranges. If the input date was `2015-01-01`, what would the ranges be? Especially the `>12 months` one.

Comment: So if input date was 2015-01-01, then sum data over next 3 months period(jan to Mar), then sum from (Apr to Jun) and so on. And >12 meaning for after the year from the chosen point of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could categorise your `dueDate` values and then use PIVOT like this:

```
WITH categorised AS (
  SELECT
    Balance,
    Range = CASE
      WHEN dueDate < DATEADD(MONTH,  3, @Date) THEN '0-3 Months'
      WHEN dueDate < DATEADD(MONTH,  6, @Date) THEN '3-6 Months'
      WHEN dueDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 12, @Date) THEN '6-12 Months'
      ELSE '>12 Months'
    END
  FROM
    dbo.YourTable
  WHERE
    Company = @Company
    AND dueDate >= @Date
)
SELECT
  [0-3 Months],
  [3-6 Months],
  [6-12 Months],
  [>12 Months]
FROM
  categorised
PIVOT
  (
    SUM(Balance)
    FOR Range IN ([0-3 Months], [3-6 Months], [6-12 Months], [>12 Months])
  ) AS p
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- based on what you have...
declare @date date = '2015-09-01'

;with cte as (
select
     Company
    ,case when datediff(month,create_date,@date) between 0 and 2 then Balance else 0 end as '0-3 Months'
    ,case when datediff(month,create_date,@date) between 3 and 5 then Balance else 0 end as '3-6 Months'
    ,case when datediff(month,create_date,@date) between 6 and 11 then Balance  else 0 end as '6-12 Months'
    ,case when datediff(month,create_date,@date) > 11 then Balance else 0 end as '>12 Months'
from sys.databases
)
select
     Company
    ,sum([0-3 Months]) as [0-3 Months]
    ,sum([3-6 Months]) as [3-6 Months]
    ,sum([6-12 Months]) as [6-12 Months]
    ,sum([>12 Months]) as [>12 Months]
from cte
group by Company
```